# API call using Ansible uri module

Tags: curl, ansible, credentials

I am trying to use the [Ansible uri](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/uri_module.html) module to communicate with [DeployHQ's API](https://www.deployhq.com/support/api).

Here is the example DeployHQ's documentation that I am trying to use from Ansible:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
--user adam@atechmedia.com:my-api-key \
-d '{"deployment":{ "parent_identifier":"7563d091-ca73-588e-cfe2- e4936f190145", \
  "start_revision" : "e84b5937f1132932dd56026db26a76f406555c19", \
  "end_revision" : "e84b5937f1132932dd56026db26a76f406555c19", \
  "mode" : "queue", \
  "copy_config_files" : 1, \
  "email_notify" : 1 \
}}' http://test.deployhq.com/projects/project/deployments/
```

This is how I am sending it via Ansible:

```
- uri:
    url: https://cepr.deployhq.com/projects/cepr-live/servers
    user: me@myemail.org:secret_api_key
    body_format: json
    method: GET
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      Accept: application/json
    deployment:
      parent_identifier: id
      start_revision: my_start_rev
      end_revision: my_end_rev
      mode: queue
      copy_config_files: 1
      email_notify: 1
    return_content: yes
```

The issue is that I am getting a 403 response back (access denied), so it is something to do with passing them the --user parameters. I have no issue at all sending the cURL request from the cli, so the user creds passed in --user are correct.  DeployHQ can see from their logs that the json request looks correct but it not authenticated (obviously they cannot view the headers for security reasons).

It must be simple but I have spent all afternoon and tried many combinations of user: (including and user: and password: for the api key) - in the body: and out of the body: (as above).  DeployHQ support say they use basic http_auth and so I have tried these combinations with the parameter:

```
force_basic_auth: yes
```

I have also tried passing the --user in the url. No luck at all.

Has anyone else done this?!

SOLVED...

```
- uri:
    url: https://cepr.deployhq.com/projects/cepr-live/servers
    user: me@myemail.org
    password: secret_api_key
    force_basic_auth: yes
    ....
```

All on the same level..  Many thanks for comments making me go back to to password field.

Comment: Did you try with `user` and `password` options, instead of appending the secret key in `user`? The documentation for [ansible uri plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html) lists `user` as only the username, so I assume you need both.

Comment: Done it - and it was so simple in the end, it must have been one of the combinations I did not try,  You do need the user: and password: elements, but you also need the the 'force_basic_auth: yes' straight afterwards....

Answer (score 3):

According to the [ansible uri documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html), there is also a `password` field. It also looks like `user` is supposed to be only the username. Did you try something like:

```
- uri:
    url: https://cepr.deployhq.com/projects/cepr-live/servers
    user: me@myemail.org
    password: secret_api_key
    body_format: json
    method: GET
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      Accept: application/json
    deployment:
      parent_identifier: id
      start_revision: my_start_rev
      end_revision: my_end_rev
      mode: queue
      copy_config_files: 1
      email_notify: 1
    return_content: yes
```

Comment: Yes - I have tried just about every combination of user: and user with password.  It must be something about the basic http auth and passing in the user@myemail.com and the api key

Answer (score 0):

Set **[force_basic_auth](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html#parameter-force_basic_auth)**:

```
- name: call an api
  vars:
    cust_id: "123"
  uri:
    url: "url"
    url_username: "username"
    url_password: "password"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    method: PUT
    headers:
      xyz: true
    body_format: json
    body: "{{ cust_id }}"
```